# Partitioning data set by time intervals in R

Tags: r, dataset, partitioning

I have some observed data by hour. I am trying to subset this data by the day or even week intervals. I am not sure how to proceed with this task in `R`.

The sample of the data is below.

```
date                                 obs
2011-10-24 01:00:00                  12
2011-10-24 02:00:00                  4
2011-10-24 19:00:00                  18
2011-10-24 20:00:00                  7
2011-10-24 21:00:00                  4
2011-10-24 22:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 00:00:00                  4
2011-10-25 01:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 02:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 15:00:00                  12
2011-10-25 18:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 19:00:00                  3
2011-10-25 21:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 23:00:00                  9
2011-10-26 00:00:00                  13
2011-10-26 01:00:00                  11
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?  "Subset by day or week intervals" could be interpreted a couple different ways.

Comment: I am trying to get a subset of the data (not aggregate) based on the time constraints.

Comment: Yes, I realize you're trying to get a subset, but do you want to subset by calendar week, a week from a specific point in time, etc.?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. I want a partition by calendar week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I entered the data with the multiple spaces replaced with tabs.

```
dat$date <- as.POSIXct(dat$date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
split(dat , as.POSIXlt(dat$date)$yday)
# Notice these are not the same functions
#---------------------
$`296`
                 date obs
1 2011-10-24 01:00:00  12
2 2011-10-24 02:00:00   4
3 2011-10-24 19:00:00  18
4 2011-10-24 20:00:00   7
5 2011-10-24 21:00:00   4
6 2011-10-24 22:00:00   2

$`297`
                  date obs
7  2011-10-25 00:00:00   4
8  2011-10-25 01:00:00   2
9  2011-10-25 02:00:00   2
10 2011-10-25 15:00:00  12
11 2011-10-25 18:00:00   2
12 2011-10-25 19:00:00   3
13 2011-10-25 21:00:00   2
14 2011-10-25 23:00:00   9

$`298`
                  date obs
15 2011-10-26 00:00:00  13
16 2011-10-26 01:00:00  11
```

The POSIXlt class does not work well inside dataframes but it can ve very handy for creating time based groups. It's a list structure with these indices: 'yday', 'wday', 'year', 'mon', 'mday', 'hour', 'min', 'sec' and 'isdt'. The `cut.POSIXt` function adds divisions at other natural boundaries; E.g.

```
?cut.POSIXt
  split(dat , cut(dat$date, "week") )
```

If you wanted to sum within date:

```
tapply(dat$obs, as.POSIXlt(dat$date)$yday, sum)
#-------
296 297 298 
 47  36  24
```

Comment: Thank you, @DWin. How would you do it by weekly?

Comment: Any solutions for data frames?

Comment: To the first question use cut(dat$date, breaks="week"). To the second question .... huh? .... that is a dataframe.

Comment: my second question was regarding the sentence about POSIXit not working well inside dataframes.

Comment: I was only advising not to use `POSIXlt` as the class for the contents of dataframes. You can certainly use `POSIXct` to `POSIXlt` as an output strategy. That's really what it is for.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to partition it within data frame as you advised. How could I extract each subset now to a separate data frame?

Comment: You can index lists either by numeric position or by name. The trick with indexing these by name is to use quotes: '298' rather than raw numbers. Assuming you assigned the result to 'segdat', then these calls would give the same results: segdat[['298']] and segdat[[3]]

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a time series class such as `xts`

```
dat <- read.table(text="2011-10-24 01:00:00                  12
2011-10-24 02:00:00                  4
2011-10-24 19:00:00                  18
2011-10-24 20:00:00                  7
2011-10-24 21:00:00                  4
2011-10-24 22:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 00:00:00                  4
2011-10-25 01:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 02:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 15:00:00                  12
2011-10-25 18:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 19:00:00                  3
2011-10-25 21:00:00                  2
2011-10-25 23:00:00                  9
2011-10-26 00:00:00                  13
2011-10-26 01:00:00                  11", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

xobj <- xts(dat[, 3], as.POSIXct(paste(dat[, 1], dat[, 2])))
```

xts subsetting is very intuitive.  For all data on "2011-10-25", do this

```
xobj["2011-10-25"]
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-25 00:00:00    4
#2011-10-25 01:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 02:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 15:00:00   12
#2011-10-25 18:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 19:00:00    3
#2011-10-25 21:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 23:00:00    9
```

You can also subset out time spans like this (all data between and including 2011-10-24 and 2011-10-25)

```
xobj["2011-10-24/2011-10-25"]
```

Or, if you want all data from October 2011,

```
xobj["2011-10"]
```

If you want to get all data from any day that is between 19:00 and 20:00,

```
xobj['T19:00:00/T20:00:00']
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-24 19:00:00   18
#2011-10-24 20:00:00    7
#2011-10-25 19:00:00    3
```

You can use the `endpoints` function to find the rows that are the last rows of a time period ("hours", "days", "weeks", etc.)

```
endpoints(xobj, "days")
[1]  0  6 14 16
```

Or you can convert to a lower frequency

```
to.weekly(xobj)
#           xobj.Open xobj.High xobj.Low xobj.Close
#2011-10-26        12        18        2         11
to.daily(xobj)
#           xobj.Open xobj.High xobj.Low xobj.Close
#2011-10-25        12        18        2          2
#2011-10-26         4        12        2          9
#2011-10-26        13        13       11         11
```

Notice that the above creates columns for Open, High, Low, and Close.  If you only want the data at the endpoints, you can use `OHLC=FALSE`

```
to.daily(xobj, OHLC=FALSE)
#           [,1]
#2011-10-25    2
#2011-10-26    9
#2011-10-26   11
```

For more basic subsetting, and much more, visit http://www.quantmod.com/examples/

As @JoshuaUlrich mentions in the comments, `split.xts` is INCREDIBLY useful.

You can split by day (or week, or month, etc), apply a function, then recombine

```
split(xobj, 'days') #create a list where each element is the data for a different day
#[[1]]
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-24 01:00:00   12
#2011-10-24 02:00:00    4
#2011-10-24 19:00:00   18
#2011-10-24 20:00:00    7
#2011-10-24 21:00:00    4
#2011-10-24 22:00:00    2
#
#[[2]]
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-25 00:00:00    4
#2011-10-25 01:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 02:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 15:00:00   12
#2011-10-25 18:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 19:00:00    3
#2011-10-25 21:00:00    2
#2011-10-25 23:00:00    9
#
#[[3]]
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-26 00:00:00   13
#2011-10-26 01:00:00   11
```

Suppose you want only the first value of each day.  `split` by day, `lapply` the `first` function and `rbind` back together.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(xobj, 'days'), first))
#                    [,1]
#2011-10-24 01:00:00   12
#2011-10-25 00:00:00    4
#2011-10-26 00:00:00   13
```

Comment: Don't forget `split.xts`: `split(xobj, "days")`.

Comment: @GSee, thank you! For some reason running: `xobj <- xts(dat[, 3], as.POSIXct(paste(dat[, 1], dat[, 2])))` gives me an error : `order.by requires an appropriate time-based object`. Any advice?

Comment: The first argument to the function `xts` should be the data, and the second argument should be the time index.  If you copy and paste the entire first block of code in my answer, it should work (and does for me) because the first 2 columns are date and time, and the 3rd column is the data.  The vignettes in the `zoo` and `xts` packages will help you figure out how to turn your data into `xts`.  Or, if you provide the `dput` of your data, I'll update my answer for your specific data.