# Splitting data into specified time intervals in R

Tags: r

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369167/partitioning-data-set-by-time-intervals-in-r) which was helpful but I still have a few questions.  I am using a `df` with the following data:

```
                  date download  
6  2018-07-10 08:57:12     1.47  
7  2018-07-10 08:59:00     0.57
8  2018-07-10 09:01:00     0.16
9  2018-07-10 09:05:11     0.08
10 2018-07-10 09:09:12     0.09
11 2018-07-10 09:13:11     0.14
```

What I want to do is to be able to separate the data in 15 min, 30 min, and 60 min chunks based on the hour (so the intervals would be 0:00, 0:15, 0:30, 0:45, 0:60 if it was being separated based upon 15 min chunks. Currently I am using this code:

```
split(df, cut(df$date, breaks = "hour"))
```

Which in the hour case works exactly how I want and returns the following results:

```
$`2018-07-10 08:00:00`
                 date download
6 2018-07-10 08:57:12     1.47
7 2018-07-10 08:59:00     0.57

$`2018-07-10 09:00:00`
                  date download
8  2018-07-10 09:01:00     0.16
9  2018-07-10 09:05:11     0.08
10 2018-07-10 09:09:12     0.09
```

This is exactly the result I am looking for as it separates the data strictly by the hour (08:00-08:59, 09:00-09:45, etc.). However when I do:

```
split(df, cut(df$date, breaks = "30 min"))
```

I end up with the following result:

```
$`2018-07-10 08:57:00`
                  date download
6  2018-07-10 08:57:12     1.47
7  2018-07-10 08:59:00     0.57
8  2018-07-10 09:01:00     0.16
9  2018-07-10 09:05:11     0.08
10 2018-07-10 09:09:12     0.09
11 2018-07-10 09:13:11     0.14
```

While it groups it by the 30 min (or 15) interval it is starting that interval at the earliest time, in this case 08:57:00, instead of starting on the hour (09:00:00). How can I make it so that when trying to get the 15 and 30 min intervals they start on the hour like the hour interval does?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376176/counts-for-time-intervals) kind of addresses it, but you end up with a count of events within the time frame, and it is also not very elegant/flexible.  I was hoping to stick with split and cut because I am making a shiny app and it seems like it would be easier to make interactive (i.e. have a dropdown menu with the intervals which could easily be inserted straight into the split code).

Thank you!

Comment: create a lookup-table with the intervals you desire.. then use data.table's `foverlaps()` to perform an overlap-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below starting point (have to fine-tune boundaries).

Idea is to generate the cutpoints: when used on date(time), `seq` allows specifying a timeframe in days, hours, minutes for the `by` parameter.

```
library(lubridate)
date=ymd_hms(
  c("2018-07-10 08:57:12",
    "2018-07-10 08:59:00",
    "2018-07-10 09:01:00",
    "2018-07-10 09:05:11",
    "2018-07-10 09:09:12",
    "2018-07-10 09:13:11"))
download = round(runif(length(date),min=1,max=10))
df <- data.frame(date, download)

from=round(min(df$date),"hour")-hours(1)
to=round(max(df$date),"hour")+hours(1)
breaks=seq(from, to, by="30 min")
split(df,cut(df$date, breaks))
```

Leading to

```
$`2018-07-10 08:00:00`
[1] date     download
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`2018-07-10 08:30:00`
                 date download
1 2018-07-10 08:57:12        4
2 2018-07-10 08:59:00        7

$`2018-07-10 09:00:00`
                 date download
3 2018-07-10 09:01:00        5
4 2018-07-10 09:05:11        1
5 2018-07-10 09:09:12        3
6 2018-07-10 09:13:11        4

$`2018-07-10 09:30:00`
[1] date     download
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```